# Set focus on unloading window at onunload

Tags: javascript, window.onunload

I have got a confirm dialog at the onunload event. It works well but there is only one problem: the window loses at onunload the focus and passes it automatically to the parent. But since there is still the confirm dialog going on I don't want to lose the focus on this window.

I have already tried to set the focus manually with `window.focus()` but this isn't working.

At the moment my code for the onunload event looks like this:

```
window.onunload = sessionConfirmation;
function sessionConfirmation(e) {
    window.focus();
    confirm('test');
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what your end-game is, but I'm assuming you want a confirmation dialog to show when the user tries to leave the page. If so, you want to do this instead:

```
window.onbeforeunload = sessionConfirmation;
function sessionConfirmation(e) {
return "test";
}
```

Hope that's what you were asking for!